# Cookie Restriction Mode Bar showing underneath content

Tags: magento2, cookie

I have enabled the cookie restriction mode and the bar at the bottom of the page is being overlapped by the content on the page.

If any one faced this issue before please guide me.

Thank You

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: We are using a theme called Porto https://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/documentation/